# Pandas: Merging multiple very large dataframes (too slow)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 100 files to merge, and each file has 100 million rows with index as the key. The number of columns for each is only 2.
I have tried using `pandas` for merging them together, but it seems like joining or merging for more than 10 million rows `dataframe` is very slow.
Is there other efficient methods combining the data together? Memory is not an issue, I am using 256GByte memory server.

```
filenames = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4',....]
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=index_col) for filename in filenames)]
dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])
```

---

I gave up using `pandas` for merging the data. Instead, I have used `hash table` to combine the data and convert the data into a `Dataframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try feeding the read CSVs to `pd.concat()`, it may be faster:

```
filenames = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4',....]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=index_col) for filename in filenames)], axis=1)
```